# Windows 7 Access is Denied

Tags: windows-7

I'm trying to build the boost examples. I get the following error:

```
Access is denied.
Access is denied.
...found 9 targets...
...updating 2 targets...
gcc.compile.c++ bin\gcc\debug\hello.o
Access is denied.

    "g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O0 -fno-inline -Wall -g     -c -o "bin\gcc\debu
g\hello.o" "hello.cpp"

...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin\gcc\debug\hello.o...
...skipped <pbin\gcc\debug>hello.exe for lack of <pbin\gcc\debug>hello.o...
...failed updating 1 target...
...skipped 1 target...
```

I'm not familiar with Windows 7, but I believe I have the correct access rights:
[image: permissions]

Can anyone shed some light on this error? Thanks.

Update:

Process Manager finds hundreds of non-SUCCESS results for bjam. A typical line, if it helps, has the properties:

```
Desired Access: Read Attributes
Disposition:    Open
Options:    Open Reparse Point
Attributes: n/a
ShareMode:  Read, Write, Delete
AllocationSize: n/a
```

I'm not sure how to act on this though.

Comment: In Process Monitor, you can simply search for "DENIED" to find the relevant line...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to debug permission problems is to use the [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) tool from Microsoft - there you can easily see on which object (file) and for which user the access denied error is occuring.

Comment: Thanks, I'll update with some more info, but I'm unsure how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 1):

The string `bin\gcc\debug\hello.o` implies that it is trying to put an object file in the compiler's installation directory. You don't have permission to write there. You need to make it put its files in your `hello` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on folder -> Properties

Security Tab

Click on Advanced button

Owner tab

Edit.. button

select Administrators in 'Change owner to', check 'replace owner on subcontainers and objects'..this might take a while